# Suspicious "sys0972500-1.php", I didn't put it on my server

Tags: malware

Before 2 days I found inside the httpdocc a new folder which name was **css**. Inside this folder I found a file named **sys0972500-1.php** , which it caused send thousands spam emails from my server.

I deleted it and today I had the same problem.

What moves should for prevent this?

The website I have inside the httpdocs is joomla, which I have updated to the newest version and also I updated the templates.

I also changed the ftp password.

I found on the net another guy with the same problem but he didn't find a solution.

You can find the code which was inside the suspicious file by clicking the link : http://pastebin.com/NbyT5wfF

Thank you in advance

Comment: Smells like you've been hacked. See http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency for the standard answer.

Comment: Find out how they got in. Make sure they can't get in again.